# Make PHP respond to telnet (PHP Telnet Server)

Tags: php, shell, console, telnet

I have a project to do and it goes like this:

When you open a telnet console and telnet to my server, PHP should respond with:
"Hello, What is your name?"

And you type in your name and so on. How can I do this in PHP? Is it even possible?

Comment: php no, with the shell, yes. letting people tenet to your server for something trivial is not a good idea, why not make a website for 'it' ?

Comment: You mean the shell() command?

Comment: no i mean the tenet shell, which you probably should not be using anyway

Comment: No see, I'm on x10hosting. Not my own machine. I am using it as a project for something important later on.

Comment: then I would log in and type 'rm -r', i don't think you understand the implications of what your asking. what's wrong with creating a web page\form\application for this?

Comment: Again - I'm using Cpanel. Not SSH. So I can't type commands.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4677/discussion-between-techboy6601-and-dagon)

Comment: well your question says "telnet console" - so either im confused or you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

This is a good tutorial to get you started. http://devzone.zend.com/article/1086

And google is your friend here as well: http://www.google.ca/search?q=php+socket+server

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm not sure how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

[Actual TELNET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) can be a little difficult to get correct; there are a lot of control sequences that are used to influence how a terminal displays its contents.

If you simply want to write a service that people can use via TELNET, then it would probably be best to use an *existing* TELNET server (Ubuntu has several packages available, for simple TELNET: `inetutils-telnetd`, `telnetd`; for encrypted TELNET: `telnetd-ssl`; for Kerberos-authenticated TELNET: `heimdal-servers`, `krb5-telnetd`.) to provide TELNET functionality, and set your PHP program as the login shell for whichever user you want everyone to log in as. (See `passwd(5)` for information on the login shell.)

If you want to do all the socket operations *yourself*, then you'll need to use the BSD sockets support; [create a socket](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php), [bind a server name to the socket](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php), [listen on the socket](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-listen.php), and when a new connection comes in, [fork a new process to handle the new client](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php), and [accept the new connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php).

Once you have a new process with a connected client, you can use the standard read and write operations to send and receive data to the client. If you really want to support the full TELNET specification, it'll take some clever programming. If you don't mind not having access to advanced terminal features (such as provided by `readline(3)`, `ncurses(3)`, or `slang`) then you may need to drop characters with the eighth bit turned on to get rid of the TELNET control characters from your clients. (I've not tried this, because I've always used the `netcat` tool when I wanted a *clean* unencrypted and unauthenticated connection between hosts.)

Comment: Note that "fork a new process" isn't strictly necessary, but it does make handling multiple connected clients far easier.